# How to use variable as Scala type parameter?

Tags: scala

I would like to do something like the following:

```
val aoeu = List((0, 1), (0, 1, 2))
List(Tuple2, Tuple3).foreach { snth =>
  println(aoeu.filter(_.isInstanceOf[snth]).map(_.asInstanceOf[snth]))
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but it gets complex and breaks compile-time type safety. See https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20#.8ohbqsjqg

Comment: In Scala, it's easy to pass in a type and get back a value, using implicits; but it's much harder (and unsafe) to pass in a value and get back a type. In your example, it can mostly work if you replace `val snth = Product` with `type snth = Product`, except the runtime error because you're casting a `Boolean` to a `Product`. What is your actual goal?

Comment: As @Yawar pointed out after you change to `type snth = Product`, `aoeu.isInstanceOf[snth]` is a boolean and hence you can not cast it as an instance of `snth`

Comment: Yes, dumb mistake. What I really want to do is in Spark `rdd.filter(isInstanceOf[snth]).map(asInstanceOf[snth])` where `snth` is one of three subclasses of a superclass.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is something like `rdd.collect{ case v: snth => v}`.

Comment: I'm trying to refactor the common code across the three subclasses. I also don't want to be doing a `collect`.

Comment: @Yawar, I've moved the goal post and modified the question. `type` can't be used in this case.

Comment: Looks like shapeless to me.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, it's typesafe and (relatively) easy in Scala to pass in a type parameter and get back a value. What's hard and not compile-time type-safe, is going the other way. To your question as it stands, the answer is ... kinda. What we can do is define a typeclass to capture the idea of safe conversion, set up some instances for the types we're interested in, and then do our operations. So here's what I have:

```
import scala.util.Try

/**
A typeclass to represent safe casting behaviour.
*/
trait HasInstance[A] { def apply(any: Any): Option[A] }

object HasInstance {
  /**
  A helper to quickly create a typeclass instance.
  */
  private class Impl[A](_apply: Any => Option[A])
    extends HasInstance[A] {
    override def apply(any: Any): Option[A] = _apply(any)
  }

  /* Instances for standard types. */

  implicit val int: HasInstance[Int] =
    new Impl(any => Try(any.asInstanceOf[Int]).toOption)

  implicit def tuple2[A, B]: HasInstance[Tuple2[A, B]] =
    new Impl(any => Try(any.asInstanceOf[Tuple2[A, B]]).toOption)

  implicit def tuple3[A, B, C]: HasInstance[Tuple3[A, B, C]] =
    new Impl(any => Try(any.asInstanceOf[Tuple3[A, B, C]]).toOption)
}

object Test {
  def test(): Unit = {
    val xs = List((0, 1), (0, 1, 2))

    // Flatmap will automatically filter out `None` values.

    println(xs flatMap implicitly[HasInstance[Tuple2[Int, Int]]].apply)
    // ==> List((0, 1))

    println(
      xs flatMap implicitly[HasInstance[Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]]].apply)
    // ==> List((0, 1, 2))
  }
}
```

Note that we still can't capture instances in a list because their types would force Scala to upcast to `AnyRef` to store them together. If you want to have and map over heterogeneous lists, you're in Shapeless territory. In fact, you might be anyway because you'll probably want to do generic derivation to enable easily deriving instances for `HasInstance`.